# AWS: EC2: Can not login as EC2 user but only as root

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Today I started experiencing the issue where I could not connect to my EC2 instance anymore using the default `ec2-user` account. My key just gets rejected.

Weird thing is, I haven't changed my private key. What's more is that I can connect as 'root' followed by a prompt that I should use the 'ec2-user' account.

Is there any way around this issue? Has anyone experienced an issue like this? Here is my `ssh -v` output:

```
$ ssh -v -i myprivatekey.pem ec2-user@ec2-*-*-*-*.compute-1.amazonaws.com

debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to ec2-*-*-*-*.compute-1.amazonaws.com [*.*.*.*] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file epuffer_us_webserver.pem type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file epuffer_us_webserver.pem-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.4
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.4 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug1: Authenticating to ec2-*-*-*-*.compute-1.amazonaws.com:22 as 'ec2-user'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:ZMtcmC7ENUPj8jW/SRfLx+0EUsHPnfD+uje5L0Jd6Hk
debug1: Host 'ec2-*-*-*-*.compute-1.amazonaws.com' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/*/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512>
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic
debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-keyex
debug1: No valid Key exchange context
debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-with-mic
debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
No Kerberos credentials available (default cache: FILE:/tmp/krb5cc_1000)

debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
No Kerberos credentials available (default cache: FILE:/tmp/krb5cc_1000)

debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: *.pem
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
ec2-user@ec2-*-*-*-*.compute-1.amazonaws.com: Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).
```

Comment: The 'root' message is normal. Either you have an incorrect key or your ssh client is getting confused with the keys (eg too many cached). Can you edit your question to show the command you are using to connect? (You can change the IP address and keyname.)

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Added the command in the post

Comment: So you are able to ssh into the server as root? Also, which ec2-linux version are you using?

Comment: In your last login, have you done any changes to /etc/ssh/ssh_config. If you had done any mistakes while editing /etc/ssh/ssh_config, lets say adding new private key and things like that, chances are that you might have caused this issue. check who had last logged into this EC2 and ask them if anything like this has been done.

Comment: @WarrenG I run the latest amazon linux version

Comment: @PavanRao I did not change anything, simply 5 minutes after I disconnected from the server, I could no longer reconnect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the instance was launched recently-ish and is running Amazon Linux 2, then you could login using:

- [EC2 Instance Connect](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-connect-methods.html), *or*
- [AWS Systems Manager Session Manager - AWS Systems Manager](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/session-manager.html)

Once you have connected, you can replace the public key in the `/home/ec2-user/.ssh/authorized_keys` file.

Comment: I can not login using instance connect or AWS Systems Manager

Comment: Why is that? What is it saying?

Comment: It just says it is unable to connect, even though the instance is running. I created a snapshot now and am trying to mount it, however, it says the superblock is missing. Could it be that the instance just got corrupted?

Comment: EC2 Instance Connect requires the security group to open port 22 to the Instance Connect service (or just `0.0.0.0/0`). It also requires permission to use EC2 Instance Connect (which you probably have). Systems Manager Session Manager requires an agent to be installed, which is on all recent Amazon Linux images. The instance also needs an IAM Role so it can register itself with the service.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It seemed like instance connect worked after doing that little trick. Also, I found out why it no longer allowed us to connect. It seemed like someone in my staff accidentally changed the permissions of the ec2-user home directory. This caused the behavior I described.